# Redirect to new page on Ajax POST - Spring MVC

Tags: java, ajax, post

How can i open a new page on AJAX POST along the POST data. I am try to POST xml data and hence cannot do a Form POST.

For example -

I do a POST from abc.com to xyz.com. On ajax POST it should open a webpage of xyz.com which will have the POST data. I am able to receive the data on xyz.com with AJAX POST but it won't open the new webpage of xyz.com as i was trying to send html page as response.

Please help!

Comment: what have you tried so far.  I would have though a servlet forward would do the trick

Comment: 1. Tried to send html back as a response - didn't work

2. A solution that i thought - Send POST -> Save Session -> Send back Toekn -> window.open(xyz.com?token) -> GET token -> check for token -> fetch values from session/DB